# Electron file loaded but not showing in Network tab

Tags: d3.js, angular, dependencies, electron

I've packed my application with electron using:

> asar pack my-app app.asar

where `my-app` is the folder of my application.

In the index.html I have the following tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="node_modules/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script>
    //configure system loader
    System.config({defaultJSExtensions: true});
</script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //bootstrap the Angular2 application
    System.import('dist/hello').catch(console.log.bind(console));
</script>
```

In the Electron browser, in the Source section I can see all these files loaded together with their content. In the Network tab I don't see those files, but I see only the files loaded within angular application (import statements).

```
I see the main screen of my app, but in the console I see an exception:
EXCEPTION: Error in ./HelloApp class HelloApp - inline template:16:64
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
```

Using

> asar list app.asar

I can see all the files are there.

The application failed on this file `my.component.ts`

```
import {Component, Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core'; 
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {CrossSellOppty} from './cross-sell-oppty';

declare var d3: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'histogram',
    template: `
      <div>
        <svg class="chart">
        </svg>
      </div>
    ` }) export class HistogramComponent {   ...

    ngOnChanges (changes) {
      ...
      if (changes.hasOwnProperty("histogramData")) {
        d3.select(...)
      }
    } }
```

It fails on like `d3.select(...)` line.
 Do you have an idea what can cause this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing `d3` attempts to detect the type of environment it's loaded in (browser or Node) and will only set the `d3` global if it thinks it's in a browser. In an Electron window with Node integration enabled it probably assumes it should act like a CommonJS module and expects the user to load it via `require` or some other module loader.

You could import/require `d3` instead of loading it via `script src`, e.g.

```
<script>
  var d3 = require('d3')
</script>
```

Though in your case you may need to use `System.import` instead of `require`.

Other options are covered in the [Electron FAQ](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v1.1.3/docs/faq/electron-faq.md#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron).